# PowerApp Datavserse

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse, powerapps-collection

Can we create specific rows access in a table for different users?
for example, if we have different departments, can we give access to x department-related entries to one user and y department-related entries to another.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/wp-security-cds ... time for some light reading.

Comment: Manuals indeed… assign to business units or teams and manage it via that route